# How to set hover of the block which contains icon with HTML or CSS?

Tags: html, css

How to set hover of the block which contains icon with HTML or CSS?

```
<!doctype html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <body>
<a class="link1" href="www.facebook.com">
  <div id="top_head">
   <i class="fa fa-home">
  </div>
</a> 
<style>
  .fa-home {
   color: white;
   font-size: 30px;
   background-color: transparent; 
}
  #top_head {
   background-color: blue;
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   top: 20px;
   left: 300px;
   height: 70px;
   width: 100px;
}
link1:hover {
   background-color: black;
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
}             
</style>
</head>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's an example:

[image]

Comment: You forgot a dot at the beginning of the `link1:hover` selector. Also, your HTML is inside out: the body never goes inside the head.

Comment: please explain better what you want to achieve and where you got stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2kaeo5zb/)**

```
.fa-home {
    color: white;
    font-size: 30px;
    background-color: transparent;
    vertical-align:middle; /* added this */
}
#top_head {
    background-color: blue;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 300px;
    height: 40px;   /* added this */
}
a.link1:link, a.link1:active, a.link1:visited {  /* added this */
    float:left;
    display:block;
    line-height:38px;
    padding:0px 10px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    color:#fff;
}
a.link1:hover {
    background-color: black;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="top_head"> <a class="link1" href="#">   <i class="fa fa-home"></i> </a>
    <a class="link1" href="#">   home </a>
</div>
```

Comment: But icon does not occurs. If you ask me I will send you my all code may I have made any other mistake. I am new so please help.

Comment: you can edit in my demo and show relevant code, so i can make a try :)

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/6G2OgjBlRizKPCAYvBt6?p=preview                        This is my code read the description and change it. Please!!!  If you complete that so please comment

Answer (score 0):

Please update your code as follows:

```css
.fa-home {
   color: white;
   font-size: 30px;
   background-color: transparent; 
}
  #top_head {
   background-color: blue;
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   top: 20px;
   left: 300px;
 
   width: 600px;
}
.link1{padding:7px 9px; display:inline-block;}
.link1:hover {
   background-color: black;
  
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <div id="top_head">
  <a class="link1" href="www.facebook.com">
   <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
   </a> 
  </div>
```

Comment: But icon does not occurs. If you ask me I will send you my all code may I have made any other mistake. I am new so please help.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/6G2OgjBlRizKPCAYvBt6?p=preview This is my code read the description and change it. Please!!! If you complete that so please comment

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add this to your code `<html>` and after closing `head` tag `body` starts. Make that correct

Check the snippet below..

```css
.fa-home {
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  background-color: transparent;
}
#top_head {
  background-color: blue;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 300px;
  width: 600px;
}
.link1:hover {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div id="top_head">
  <a class="link1" href="www.facebook.com">
    <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: But icon does not occurs. If you ask me I will send you my all code may I have made any other mistake. I am new so please help.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you were targeting the wrong element for hover.

Just check out this plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/hdHKIN?p=preview

modified the `link:hover` to this:

```
  #top_head:hover {
     background-color: black;
     width: 200px;
     height: 200px;
  }
```

Comment: But icon does not occurs. If you ask me I will send you my all code may I have made any other mistake. I am new so please help.